# Firebase experiment does not show custom event as goal metric

Tags: ab-testing, firebase-ab-testing

I am using firebase to do some A/B testing on my app. Currently, I am trying to validate if the experiment is setup correctly. I am facing the following issues:

1. I have 3 variants A,B and C. I can see that on the debug devices, users have been assigned to each of the variants. However, there is not data for the goal event on any of the variants
2. Some of the events that have been passed to firebase do not appear in the list of events to select as the goal.

Comment: Did you manage to get your events in the metrics list at the end? I currently have the same problem that my custom events don't appear as metrics

Comment: Same here...anybody got an idea?

Comment: Any news on this issue??